# Blazor - binding select field created using markupstring

Tags: blazor

I am trying to bind the value of a select field that's to be generated through markupstring. The select appears fine but the value is not bound as intended. How can I fix my code so that the select field can be bound to the variable possibleValue?

```
<p>
    @selectBarGeneration
    Your selected value is @possibleValue
</p>

@code {

    public string possibleValue;
    private MarkupString selectBarGeneration = new MarkupString("<select @bind=\"possibleValue\"><option>Default</option><option>Option 2</option></select>");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MarkupString is not used for logic, it is there to render raw HTML strings. Attempting to place logic in raw HTML is a security concern.

Instead of using MarkupString, create the select list using Razor or even better use the InputSelect component.

```
<select @bind="@selectedValue">
            @foreach (var item in selectListItems)
            {
                <option value="@item">@item</option>
            }
        }
</select>

@code {
     string selectedValue ="";
     string[] selectListItemsv = { ... };
}
```

```
    <InputSelect @bind-Value="model.SelectedItemString" class="form-control">
           @foreach (var cnt in model.Countries)
           {
               <option value="@cnt.Id">@cnt.Name</option>
           }
     </InputSelect>
```

A third option is to use ready made components like these: https://telerik.com/blazor-ui

Comment: I just got into Blazor recently and it hadn't cross my mind to use another Razor component, and I'm still not very familiar with the different components yet. Tried both of them and it works, thank you so much !

Comment: No worries, got to start somewhere. Good luck!